# Anchor Tag on Address Bar messing up page-scroll. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github

I recently purchased my first domain through google domains and set it up with Github pages. My `account.github.io` now properly redirects to `mywebsite.com`.

In this website I used anchor tags for same page scrolls with bootstrap, to give it the smooth scroll animation. After waiting for the domain to work, this smooth animation stopped working since clicking on tabs now redirects to the section, like this:

`mywebsite.com/#tag`

Instead of a simple

`mywebsite.com`

All these tags are under `index.html`

I believe this is messing up the `page-scroll` animation. On the other hand, the tag `#page-top` works fine and has an animation. Everything was working well on `account.github.io` til I started using the custom domain.

This is a bit confusing to explain but I hope you could understand and maybe help me find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: can you share the code ? what about browser console? it should show errors after clicking navigation items, because by default it should "preventDefault" the click so #tag won't be added to url, instead it should continue with the function, which in your case should be scrolling to position X on page

Comment: I saw the console and found this:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).collapse is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (navbar.js:32)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.i (jquery.min.js:3)`
I'm going to try and find a solution with that